# как сделать чтобы при клике на дочерний b-dropdown, родительский не закрывался? vue-bootstrap

Tags: javascript, vue.js, bootstrap-vue

```
<b-dropdown id="dropdown-1" text="Dropdown Button" class="m-md-2">
    <b-dropdown id="dropdown-2" text="Dropdown Button" class="m-md-2">
        <b-dropdown-item>First Action</b-dropdown-item>
        <b-dropdown-item>Second Action</b-dropdown-item>
        <b-dropdown-item>Third Action</b-dropdown-item>
        <b-dropdown-divider></b-dropdown-divider>
        <b-dropdown-item active>Active action</b-dropdown-item>
        <b-dropdown-item disabled>Disabled action</b-dropdown-item>
    </b-dropdown>
</b-dropdown>
```

Answer (score 0):

Событие клика всплывает (`bubbles`) наверх по DOM-дереву. Это значит, что слушатели на клике родителя отработают, если событие произойдет на потомках.
Для того, чтобы отменить всплытые, используется `event.stopPropagation()`. Причем отменить всплытие можно на любом уровне.

```js
function log(event) {
  console.log(event.currentTarget.className);
}

function logAndStop(event) {
  event.stopPropagation();
  console.log(event.currentTarget.className);
}
```

```html
<div class="root" onclick="log(event)">
  <div class="parent" onclick="log(event)">
    <div class="child" onclick="log(event)">Bubbling up to top</div>
  </div>
</div>

<hr>

<div class="root" onclick="log(event)">
  <div class="parent" onclick="logAndStop(event)">
    <div class="child" onclick="log(event)">Stop bubbling to root</div>
  </div>
</div>

<hr>

<div class="root" onclick="log(event)">
  <div class="parent" onclick="log(event)">
    <div class="child" onclick="logAndStop(event)">Stop bubbling at all</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Среда исполнения не имеет значения. Это может быть `Vue`, `Angular`, `React` или просто ванильный `JS`. Все они дают средства работать с `Event` объектом.

```
<span @click="(event) => event.stopPropagation()">Log me</span>
```